# PostgreSQL installation hangs after password prompt

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, postgresql

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on an AWS cloud CPU instance (instance type: [c5.24xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/), Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

I have tried both `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib`, as well as installing from the apt repository mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

However, in both cases the installation keeps freezing at this point:

```
Setting up postgresql-common (247.pgdg20.04+1) ...
Password:
```

Here after I enter a password and press enter, nothing happens and the installation seems to be stuck.

Then if I cancel via Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D, it blocks any further installations and I need to kill all apt and dpkg processes, delete the dpkg lock files, and purge postgresql from my system before trying again.

I have been stuck on this for a while...is there any way to fix this issue and install postgresql? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! There isn't quite enough info here to offer an answer. Could you [edit] your question to include which cloud provider and which instance size is being used? Could you also explain how you installed PostgreSQL? Is it from the default sources or a 3rd-party source? With this information, it will be easier to offer some useful suggestions 

Comment: @matigo Thank you for your comment, I have made the edits as you suggested.

Comment: Hi, asking just to be sure, did you update repositories with "sudo apt update" before installing?

Comment: Yes, I did run "sudo apt update"